# Support plugins in c program

Tags: c, plugins

As I have said in title I want to create a program in C (pure C not C++) that supports plugins but I don't know how to implement that. Some ideas about the implemention might me be helpful

**Edit** : By some googling I found out that it is called plugin framework

Comment: What do you mean by plugin?

Comment: @Jens : I want to let the users write a plugin for my program

Comment: You may want to look into function pointers.

Comment: I know them but I will be grateful for examples

Comment: A quick search for the term gives me a lot of examples and tutorials. Would you need more than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not said what platform you're interested in, but assuming its Linux take a look at [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) web page.

To use it you'd first have to find the filename of the dynamic link library you want to load. That could be done via a configuration file, or by searching for files in a set directory, a command line switch, or simply selected by the user of the program.

Then all you'd have to do is decide on a set of routines that the dynamic link library would be expected to implement. You'd find those using the dlsym() function, casting the result to whatever pointer type (either a variable type or a function pointer type) you have decided on.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon on SO.

Comment: @JensGustedt Hadn't finished!

Comment: Actually I'm using Windows!